# How do I throttle bandwidth-speed for internal ip-addresses using tc command and cbq-only filter?

Tags: limit, bandwidth-throttling, trafficshaping

I want to limit bandwidth-speed of internal ip-addresses (like 10.8.0.1) and had been trying to use the following rules:

```
tc qdisc add dev tun1 root handle 1: cbq avpkt 1000 bandwidth 3000mbit
tc class add dev tun1 parent 1: classid 1:1 cbq rate 1mbit allot 1500 prio 1 bounded isolated
tc qdisc add dev tun1 parent 1: sfq perturb 10
tc filter add dev tun1 parent 1: protocol ip prio 16 u32 match ip src {IP_HERE} flowid 1:1
```

These rules work perfect with '**non**-internal' ip-addresses but don't work with internals.
I am unable to use htb filter because my VPS is based on OpenVZ and the kernel doesn't support it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue which is quite easy.

Just had to change source to destination. So, the last command will be like this:

```
tc filter add dev tun1 parent 1: protocol ip prio 16 u32 match ip dst {IP_HERE} flowid 1:1
```